# How can I synchronize a List variable, that is accessed by multiple thread In a Factory design pattern (Single Instance)

Tags: java, multithreading, variables, concurrency, synchronization

```
public class Rule{
 private Integer ruleId;
 private String name;
 private Date startdate;
 private Date endDate;

 // getters & setters
}
public class ClassA{
  public static List<Rule> ruleList = new ArrayList<Rule>();
  public void populateRule(){
   //Retrieve all rules; Here the rules are being added or deleted by the administration.
   //So it is required to retrieve the rules every time the Job runs.
    ruleList.clear();
    ruleList.addAll(RuleService.retrieveRules());
  }
}

public class UserClassA1{
  ClassA oClassA=Factory.getInstance(ClassA.class);
  List<Rule> rules=oClassA.populateRule();
  for(Rule oRule:rules){
  // do some stuff.
  } 
}
public class UserClassA2{
 ClassA oClassA=Factory.getInstance(ClassA.class);
List<Rule> rules=oClassA.populateRule();
for(Rule oRule:rules){
  // do some stuff.
  } 
}
```

---

Here UserClassA1 & UserClassA2 are doing different activity but both using the same static list & when they begin they resets the list and populates the new one.

My problem is that when UserClassA1 started working after populating the list,UserClassA2 begins it's execution and cleares the list and then goes to populate the list.In this time gap after clearing the list till populating it,UserClassA1 is not functioning properly as the list is cleared.

I want a lock on the ruleList List, so that while any of the instance is populating the list no other instance will use the list.

Help pls..

Comment: Why populate the static list instead of just `return RuleService.retrieveRules()`?

Comment: Why do you need synchronization at all? You always repopulate the list (at least in the examples you provided). Just `return RuleService.retrieveRules()` would work for UserClassA and UserClassB. Or do you want to cache the list?

Comment: You got it right, I am cacheing the rules for batch processing and the list is being used by different programs, But the thing is that the rules are depended on current date & time, so when starting a batch processing I need to refresh the list.And I can't return the list as we are using multi layers and the list is being used in all the layers(BizService,Service,DaoService etc).

Answer (score 1):

In classA, declare your ruleList as a CopyOnWriteArrayList (in java.util.concurrent). Each time the list is changed, a new copy will me made. Existing iterators on the list will be unaffected by any write operations.

This way, you will still have one instance of ruleList, but it will be thread safe.

Javadoc : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html

Answer (score 0):

The standard answer would be, wrap the code accessing the list in `synchronized(ClassA.ruleList) { ... }`. Messing with `synchronized` primitives etc is however error prone and you should always try to use the higher level constructs from `java.util.concurrent`, such as `Lock`.

In this case however, I would encourage you to consider refactoring the code slightly. How about making `ruleList` a local variable in the factor method for instance?

Comment: Would synchronizing in classA not be better than at the client end?

Comment: If properly designed, yes. I noted that the client does `for (Rule oRule:rules)` on the same list though, which could cause concurrent modification exceptions. (Complete mess imo.)

Comment: There are other methods in the ClassA & other classes which accesses the list.And in a given instance there can be more than one job(thread) running.Making the ClassA synchronize will not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you need to view the list in a consistent state (fully populated). You could start by making `ruleList` private. And to make sure that 2 threads can't populate it concurrently, make `populateRule` synchronized.

But unless `ClassA` has other methods that need access to `ruleList`, a defensive, thread safe and simpler version of your class could be:

```
public class ClassA{
    public void populateRule() {
        //Retrieve all rules; Here the rules are being added or deleted by the administration.
        //So it is required to retrieve the rules every time the Job runs.
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(RuleService.retrieveRules());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple (albeit brute force) way is to use [`Collections.synchronizedList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29);

```
public static List<Rule> ruleList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Rule>());
```

Comment: That requires additional synchronization in UserClassA1 and UserClassA2.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider changing `ClassA` to hand out new lists to each caller of `populateRule` method. That way, the caller can use the returned list whatever way they feel fit without worrying about subsequent invocations of `populateRule`. For eg:

```
public class ClassA {
  public List<Rule> populateRule() {
    // Retrieve all rules; Here the rules are being added or deleted by 
    // the administration. So it is required to retrieve the rules every 
    // time the Job runs.
    return new ArrayList(RuleService.retrieveRules());
  }
}
```

Comment: My intention is to buffer the rules for execution of batch jobs.And the buffer is in a file that is shared by multiple jobs and are used by different leyers.And we are following the Factory Pattern to achieve singleton pattern. So I can't return the list. And for every invocation i need to get the lettest set of rules.

Comment: I want to know the way, how can i restrict ather threades to access the contains while any other thread is executing  populateRule() method, if populating the list

Comment: @MrinmoySen `ClassA` returns a new list to the batch jobs every time they call `populateRule()` method. This new list returned contains every rule that was fetched by `RuleService.retrieveRules()` at the time `ClassA.populateRule()` was called.

Comment: No ClassA do not return a List it just Buffers the List.
As we are using Factory Design pattern to achieve singleton.That's the buffered list is available for the callers.

Comment: @MrinmoySen I was suggesting that you change the code such that `ClassA.populateRule` returns a new list on every invocation.